# How do I force phones to recognize international numbers on my website?

Tags: php, html, drupal, mobile, meta-tags

I have an international phone number outputting on a website. For example:

```
<span class="phone-number">+1 918 555 5555</span>
```

My iphone is smart enough to recognize this as a phone number and call it but it removes the "+" sign from the number. So if my friend from mexico was to click on it he would get an invalid number.

Is their some meta-data I can use or any way I can force mobile phones to add that plus sign preserving the international number?

Comment: Have you had your friend from Mexico try it? It could just be removing the country code because you're in the same country.

Comment: Sorry this was a hypothetical. I don't actually have a friend in mexico. And yes I have verified this is true for users outside the country as well. Good thought though. My actual use case involves country codes from around the world and callers from around the world. Good thoughts though. I would have asked the same question.

Comment: http://www.designified.com/blog/article/75/better-iphone-automatic-number-dialling-from-a-webpage one of several pages i found

Comment: That looks right. I'll try it out. Try adding it as an answer with a bit more info so I can select it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrapping it in an `<a>` tag like this lets you use any format you'd like:

```
<a href="tel:+19185555555">+1 918 555 5555</a>
```

More info on the various formats you can take advantage of *without* adding any code [here](http://hjacob.com/blog/2009/07/making-a-phone-number-clickable-for-iphone-users/).